# how can I display opencart total on external web page from cart

Tags: php, opencart

How can I display the $total on an external web page from opencart. The web page and opencart are on the same server but opencart is installed in a sub folder. I would like to display the Total and a link back to opencart. I have the link as follows so far:

```
  <div id="topcart">
    <p>
      <span class="cartamt">$123.00</span>
      <a href="/store/index.php?route=checkout/checkout"><img src="/images/icon-cart.png" alt="Cart" /></a>
    </p>
  </div><!-- end div topcart -->
```

I just need to replace the 123.00 with the actual total amount in opencart.
Thanks,
Robert Campbell

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this would be to save the total as `getTotal()` is called in the cart class to a session variable, and then use the session variable in that page (assuming they are on the same domain and using the same session). To set the session variable, use

```
$this->session->data['currentTotal'] = $total;
```

Just before `return $total;` in `system/library/cart.php`. Adding currency formatting gets a little more tricky. You instead need to use

```
global $registry;
$this->session->data['currentTotal'] = $registry->get('currency')->format($total);
```

After that, in your non OC page start a session if it's not already started, and add

```
<?php echo empty($_SESSION['currentTotal'] ? '$0.00' : $_SESSION['currentTotal']); ?>
```

In the place of your $123.00

Comment: I tried this because it looks really simple and strait forward. But it seems that function is not getting called at all. I added an error_log() statement and it never reaches that function.

Comment: Did you start a session in your static page? Also, did you visit your shopping cart before the page?

Comment: I ended up adding this to the file: /catalog/controller/common/header.php after the totals are calculated, about line 70 ...         global  $registry;
        $this->session->data['currentTotal'] = $registry->get('currency')->format($total);  ...  Now all I need to do is find where the cart is updated with javascript on the current page so I can update the value in the header and the session because it does not go into the session unless I reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else trying to find this answer it's simple. Edit the `system/library/cart.php` file like jay says but when getting the total use
`$_SESSION['default']['currentTotal']` instead.